# Post archive link redirects me to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my link to the post archive page to work. The posts themselves seem to work just fine it's just the archive page that seems to be inaccessible. I added the following link to the archive on the homepage:

`<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'View all posts', 'text-domain'); ?></a>`

And then I did the same for a custom post type switching out `'post'` for the `'custom-post'`. The custom post-type correctly links to the archive page but the default post just redirects me to the homepage. What could I be doing wrong here?

**Side note:** 
I have a custom permalink structure simply set to `/%category%/%postname%/` and left the category and tag base empty. I also made sure to flush settings by saving the permalinks.